# One consumer_key & consumer_secret for woocommerce REST-API in every subsite of wp network (wordpress multisite)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce-rest-api, multisite

I have installed wordpress multisite; and install woocommerce on it for each subsite. I am using woocommerce rest-api for developing mobile app with backend of woocommerce. Is there any way to use a single (master) consumer_key and consumer_secret for do rest requests? For now I have to use every sub-sites `ck_` and `cs_`. Passing them through app and site is security penalty.

Answer (score 0):

I installed this plugin: "WordPress Multisite User Sync/Unsync", then I create an admin (super admin) user and activate its application password (from user section of admin side). After that, I changed the auth method of my app to `basic auth`. In this way you can use your username and its depending application passwords for authentication.